# Specifying Android boot up custom resolution (in DIP)

Tags: android, resolution, boot, density-independent-pixel

I am developing for several different screen sizes with different DIP. While it's not a problem with AVDs, I would like to test it on a real device. I have a large screen to which my board is hooked up to. But how can I boot Android up with a custom resolution? Where is that specified?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it change resulation in device properies.You can give size also.

Comment: I can find a lot of references regarding getting configurations and values from "device properties". There isn't seem to be too much resources regarding changing the properties. Could you give me a few more pointers? Does this mean I have to build a new kernel? And upload a new ROM?

Comment: As far as i know Android takes the screen sizes from the kernel, so you'd change the resolution there... if your driver allows... The other guy is probably referring to the emulator :)